# Passing Array from one UIViewController to other ViewController returning null

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to pass Array from one `UIViewController` to other viewcontroller.
I tried using property (viewcontroller1.array).
I tried notifications (posting notification and adding observer ).
I tried `NSUserDefaults` 
all are returning a null array.

Comment: Add your tried code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Answer (score 1):

in ViewController 1 from array is to passed

```
@interface demopreseViewController () {
    NSArray* nameArr;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    nameArr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Jill Valentine", @"Peter Griffin",nil];
    NSLog(@"%@",nameArr);

}

- (IBAction)PresentAction:(id)sender {
    ViewController2 *aviewcontroller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"aa"];
    aviewcontroller.array1 = nameArr;
    [self presentViewController:aviewcontroller animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

In viewController 2 Where array is to be passed

under ViewController2.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *array1;
```

under ViewController2.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"parsed%@",_array1);
}
```

Array Data will be passed

Comment: .I tried the above type steps  already but still null array iam getting. is it mandatory to give like this "    ViewController2 *aviewcontroller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"aa"];". ? when I gave the above line iam getting unrecognized selector sent to instance error.  ofcourse I had given the identifier with the name i specified to my storyboard.I have many storyboard files in the project? does it make difference if I give self.storyboard?

Comment: Did you tried using identifier of storyboard like Below
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard"   bundle: nil];

Comment: @sampath, `viewConrtoller2` is the name of view controller's class so you need to give yours.

Comment: I have tried below code and it worked. **MViewController *nextVC =(MViewController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Service"]; **

Answer (score 0):

Define the property for Your Arrays

```
@Property(nonatomic, retain) NSArray *arrayName;
```

Secondly

```
ViewControllerClassName *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"StoryboardIdentifier"];
controller.array = arrayName;
```